# How can I insert the message results of a query into a #temptable in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I run this command in the Management Studio:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TBL_NAME', RESEED, 0);
```

output is:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '0', current column value '0'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

I would like to get that output and insert it into a `#temptable`, any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch the output of a DBCC-Statement in a temptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946813/how-to-catch-the-output-of-a-dbcc-statement-in-a-temptable)

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to get the latest generated identity for a specific table and store it to a temp table, starting from SQL Server 2008 R2, you can use the IDENT_CURRENT function like this:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TBL_NAME') AS CurrentIdentity
INTO #temptable
```

For earlier versions of SQL Server, you can access the

```
SELECT IC.last_value AS CurrentIdentity
INTO #temptable
FROM sys.identity_columns IC
     INNER JOIN sys.objects O ON IC.object_id=O.object_id
WHERE O.object_id=OBJECT_ID('TBL_NAME')
```

Capturing the PRINT output of DBCC or any other stored procedure is possible with many limitations through the OUTPUTBUFFER function like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TBL_NAME', RESEED, 0);
CREATE TABLE #temptable TABLE ([Buffer] NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @output
EXEC ('DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)')
SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

I would strongly discourrage the use of OUTPUTBUFFER except for troubleshooting purposes.