# Get current value of SET STATISTICS [XML|TIME|IO]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, how can I retrieve the current configuration value that can be set with these commands?

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS XML ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

I looked into `@@OPTIONS` but the [value list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't mention them. Any other magic variable or system table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DBCC USEROPTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-useroptions-transact-sql) will return the settings as a result set:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
```

Sample result:

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
|       Set Option        |     Value      |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| textsize                | 2147483647     |
| language                | us_english     |
| dateformat              | mdy            |
| datefirst               | 7              |
| statistics time         | SET            |
| statistics io           | SET            |
| statistics XML          | SET            |
| lock_timeout            | -1             |
| quoted_identifier       | SET            |
| arithabort              | SET            |
| ansi_null_dflt_on       | SET            |
| ansi_warnings           | SET            |
| ansi_padding            | SET            |
| ansi_nulls              | SET            |
| concat_null_yields_null | SET            |
| isolation level         | read committed |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```

The results can be inserted into a temp table or variable for additional querying/filtering. This example includes the options of interest and performs a LEFT JOIN to include options that may not be set too:

```
DECLARE @results TABLE(
     SetOption sysname
    ,Value nvarchar(46)
);
INSERT INTO @results(SetOption, Value)
    EXEC(N'DBCC USEROPTIONS;');
SELECT
      so.SetOption 
    , COALESCE (Value, N'NOT SET') AS Value
FROM (VALUES
     (N'statistics time')
    ,(N'statistics xml')
    ,(N'statistics io')
) AS so(SetOption)
LEFT JOIN @results AS r ON r.SetOption = so.SetOption;

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
SET STATISTICS XML OFF;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
DECLARE @results TABLE(
     SetOption sysname
    ,Value nvarchar(46)
);
INSERT INTO @results(SetOption, Value)
    EXEC(N'DBCC USEROPTIONS;');
SELECT
      so.SetOption 
    , COALESCE (Value, N'NOT SET') AS Value
FROM (VALUES
     (N'statistics time')
    ,(N'statistics xml')
    ,(N'statistics io')
) AS so(SetOption)
LEFT JOIN @results AS r ON r.SetOption = so.SetOption;
```

Results:

```
+-----------------+---------+
|    SetOption    |  Value  |
+-----------------+---------+
| statistics time | NOT SET |
| statistics xml  | NOT SET |
| statistics io   | SET     |
+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In case anyone else tries to process the output in their stored proc or otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946813/how-to-catch-the-output-of-a-dbcc-statement-in-a-temptable

Comment: @Hannobo, I added an example to expand on that technique.